# Why is my program not compiling properly?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I keep getting an error when Im compiling my code. I believe my logic is fine and everything but I must have made a error while creating the BushelBasket class.  I was told not to alter the main method in any way by my instructor. Thanks for any help in advance!

```
public class AppleOrchard
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Rick...");
        BushelBasket rick = new BushelBasket(0);
        rick.print();
        rick.pick(11);
        rick.pick(22);
        rick.print();
        rick.eat(4);
        rick.print();
        rick.spill();
        rick.print();

        System.out.println("Newt...");
        BushelBasket newt = new BushelBasket(100);
        newt.print();

        System.out.println( newt.isEmpty() );
        System.out.println( newt.isFull() );
        System.out.println( newt.getApples() );
        System.out.println( newt.roomLeftInBasket() );

        System.out.println("Michele...");
        BushelBasket michele = new BushelBasket(0);
        System.out.println( michele.isEmpty() );
        System.out.println( michele.isFull() );
        michele.pick(25);
        System.out.println( michele.isEmpty() );
        System.out.println( michele.isFull() );
        michele.pick(100);
        System.out.println( michele.isEmpty() );
        System.out.println( michele.isFull() );

        System.out.println("Herman...");
        BushelBasket herman = new BushelBasket(-5);  // should default to 0
        herman.print();

        System.out.println("Jon...");
        BushelBasket jon = new BushelBasket(300);  // should default to 125
        jon.print();

        System.out.println("Ron...");
        BushelBasket ron = new BushelBasket(20);  // starts with 20
        ron.print();
        ron.eat(50);  // can only eat down to zero apples
        ron.print();  // should see zero apples
        ron.eat(10);  // back to 10
        ron.pick(1000);  // basket can only hold 125 apples
        ron.print();  // should print 125

        System.out.println("Gary...");
        BushelBasket gary = new BushelBasket();  // should default to 0
        gary.print();
    }
}
class BushelBasket()
{
        public void spill()
        {
            apples = 0;
        }

        public void pick(int x)
        {
            apples = apples + x;
        }

        public void eat(int x)
        {
            apples = apples - x;
        }

        public int getApples()
        {
            return apples;  
        }

        public void print()
        {
            int x = getApples();
            System.out.println("This bushel basket has " + x + " apples in it.");
        }

        public boolean isEmpty()
        {
            int emtpy = 0;

            if (apples <= emtpy)
            {   
                return true;
            }

            else 
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public boolean isFull()
        {
            int full = 125;

            if (apples >= full)
            {   
                return true;
            }

            else 
            {
                return false;
            }

        }

        public boolean roomLeftInBasket()
        {
            int full = 125;

            if (apples < full)
            {   
                return true;
            }

            else 
            {
                return false;
            }

        }

}
```

Comment: "*I keep getting an error when Im compiling my code*" => Have you read the error message, which probably contains a line number pointing to the problematic line of code?

Comment: What compilation error are you getting?

Comment: In any case, your `BushelBasket` class should probably have an `apples` member and a constructor that takes an int.

Comment: Seems like variable apples is missing

Comment: I could imagine that System or so is not know. I don't see any Import statements. but I'm really not in the mood to try myself

Comment: I fixed the coding for it to compile, sorry for such obvious errors its really late.  Now my output isn't matching my expected output. Ill post them below in separate comments

Comment: Rick...
This bushel basket has 0 apples in it.
This bushel basket has 33 apples in it.
This bushel basket has 29 apples in it.
This bushel basket has 0 apples in it.
Newt...
This bushel basket has 100 apples in it.
false
false
100
true
Michele...
true
false
false
false
false
true
Herman...
This bushel basket has -5 apples in it.
Jon...
This bushel basket has 300 apples in it.
Ron...
This bushel basket has 20 apples in it.
This bushel basket has -30 apples in it.
This bushel basket has 960 apples in it.
Gary...
This bushel basket has 0 apples in it.

Comment: EXPECTED OUTPUTRick...
This bushel basket has 0 apples in it.
This bushel basket has 33 apples in it.
This bushel basket has 29 apples in it.
This bushel basket has 0 apples in it.
Newt...
This bushel basket has 100 apples in it.
false
false
100
25
Michele...
true
false
false
false
false
true
Herman...
This bushel basket has 0 apples in it.
Jon...
This bushel basket has 125 apples in it.
Ron...
This bushel basket has 20 apples in it.
This bushel basket has 0 apples in it.
This bushel basket has 125 apples in it.
Gary...
This bushel basket has 0 apples in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your java app can't compile.

you need to declare a variable `apples` in `BushelBasket`

and you have missing constructor that assigns `apples`

```
public BushelBasket(int apples)
{
   this.apples = apples;

}
```

BTW,

Instead of

```
class BushelBasket()
```

it should be

```
class BushelBasket
```

Comment: THANKS! I just started using constructors and was really confused. I sorted it out and found that an error in my code was settings the new BushelBasket (0) to zero (as shown) thanks! Now I just need my output to match my instructors :)

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, you forgot to declare `apples` variable and constructor too:

```
class BushelBasket {
  int apples;

  BushelBasket() {
  }  

  BushelBasket(int apples) {
    this.apples = apples;
  }

  ...
}
```

Your compiler error would be helpful, btw.

Comment: adding your code to mine i get this new error meessage AppleOrchard.java:54: error: constructor BushelBasket in class BushelBasket cannot be applied to given types;
  BushelBasket gary = new BushelBasket(); // should default to 0
                      ^
  required: int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit co

Comment: Oops, sorry, I placed unnecessary brackets after class declaration. Please try again with modified code (it works for me).

Comment: I fixed the errors and finally can run my program. However now my output is WAY off from the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

This line (and similar ones)...

```
 BushelBasket michele = new BushelBasket(0);
```

... are trying to call a constructor on `BushelBasket` with an `int` parameter. I don't see any such constructor, nor a declaration of the `apples` variable you keep referring to.

The compiler error should have been pretty clear on both these points. It's really important to read compiler error messages carefully.